# How to use the word fascination properly?

Tags: word-usage

Can we use fascination solely? For example, is the following sentence correct?

> It is crucial to first identify children’s **fascinations** before we
> start to impart an awful lot of information to them in schools.

In [dictionary samples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fascination), fascination is always collocated with some prepositions such as **for** and **with**. I wonder if it is mandatory or not. For instance, Do I have to change the above sentence to something as follows?

> It is crucial to first identify children’s **fascinations for different fields** before we start to impart an awful lot of information to them in schools.

I don't like it because I feel it is a little bit wordy. Reader can understand what kind of fascinations I am talking about. So I guess "**for different fields**" can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't common to use 'fascination' without naming a specific object; however it wouldn't be incorrect to do so, and your dictionary examples prove it.

We normally say someone has a fascination *with* something, or that they are fascinated *by* something, that is the object or subject of their fascination.

Looking at the example you mentioned using 'for':

> Mass murders hold a gruesome fascination for the public.

In this example, 'the public' is **not** the object of the fascination. It means that the public have a fascination *with* mass murder. So this is not an alternative preposition to introduce the object of a fascination.

However,this other example from the same dictionary shows that 'fascination' doesn't always need an object:

> The greatness of his poetry, and **the fascination of the era** which produced it, meanwhile remain undisputed.

Again, 'the era' is not the object of the fascination. This sentence says that the era (meaning contemporaries alive at a specific time) *had* a fascination - but the sentence does not specify what they were fascinated with. It seems safe to assume that it was a fascination with *poetry*, but it says that the fascination helped to *produce* the poetry, so it might refer to a fascination with writing or the arts in general. Perhaps the wider context of the text makes that clear, but in isolation this sentence does not mention an object of the fascination.

I have to also give an honourable mention to the Human League song '*(Keep Feeling) Fascination*', which refers to a feeling of 'fascination' without a specific object:

> Keep feeling fascination
> Passion burning
> Love so strong
> Keep feeling fascination
> Looking, learning
> Moving on

Generally speaking though, 'fascination' would have an object, either specified or implied. It is quite common to say "I'm fascinated" in response to something that has been said, so while not specifying what you are fascinated by, it is clear what you mean.